# Windows store app-ListView items not visbile

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-store-apps, json.net

In a windows store app need to bind data to a `Listview`. Data is retrived through a `WCF service` as a `JSON string` and converted in to `JArray v = JArray.Parse(result);`

In the code behind following method is implemented.

```
private async void GetGarageinfo()
{
    string location = txtLocation.Text.Trim();
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    string result = await client.GetGarageInfoAsync(location);
    try
    {
        JArray v = JArray.Parse(result);
        lstvGarages.ItemsSource = v;

    }
}
```

In the XAML file

```
<ListView Name="lstvGarages">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="900" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding GarageName}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding GarageLocation}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding GarageTP}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

When the method is called it retrieves empty records equal to the number of records that is in the array. But I can't see the `Name, Location or TP data` but empty records which are clickable.

Is there a error in the way I am binding data?

Comment: Have you create any model class for that ?

Comment: @smoothersillent No because its coming from DB as a JSON string. But I created a model class and hard coded some sample data and passed to the list just to check whether it works. But there also it was the same result

Comment: Check if your item class has public properties `GarageName`, `GarageLocation` etc. Data binding won't work with fields.

Comment: @Clemens yes they are public. I feel like its has something to do with Binding path. If I remove property name `Text="{Binding}"` it will show the `Class_library.Class_name` in those Text Blocks

Comment: @IsankaLakshan maybe it something as simple as setting the DataContext before setting the ItemsSource.   `lstvGarages.DataContext = v;`